# mentions not working in text-angular or friends tag not working in textangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
>   <text-angular  mentio
>                 mentio-typed-text="typedTerm"
>                 mentio-items="userFriends | filter:label:typedTerm"
>                 mentio-select="getPeopleTextRaw(item)"
>                 id="post-editor" placeholder="{{ 'postPlaceholder' | translate }}" ng-model="text" class=" textareanoborder col-xs-12
> col-md-12">
>                 </text-angular>
```

I have code like this when i see in browser unable to get the mention text editor also not working.